# Modificar una fecha en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi problema es que quiero sumar una determinada cantidad de horas y minutos a una fecha y guardarla el problema es que me marca error en el tipo de conversión de datos. ¿Como puedo modificar esa fecha para poder guardarla con las horas y minutos ya agregados?

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_horarios] ON [dbo].[Citas]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @hora smallint = (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,Fecha) FROM inserted)
DECLARE @minutos smallint = (SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE,Fecha) FROM inserted)
DECLARE @duracion float = (SELECT Duracion FROM inserted)
DECLARE @fecha datetime = (SELECT Fecha FROM inserted)
DECLARE @fechafin datetime = @fecha
SET @fechafin = DATEADD(hour,@hora,@fechafin)
SET @fechafin = DATEADD(minute,@minutos,@fechafin)
INSERT INTO dbo.Horarios
values(@fecha,@fecha,@fechafin)
END
```

Comment: ¿De casualidad lo que buscas es sumar la `Duracion`  a las `Fecha` para salvar en la tabla `Horarios`? si fuera así ¿`Duracion` en que se mide? horas, minutos, etc.

Comment: Si, Quiero obtener hora y minutos de la fecha insertada en la tabla de citas e insertar un registro en Horarios con la fecha modificada, es decir con las hora y minutos agregados para determinar el fin de la cita.

Answer (score 1):

En las sentencias SQL no puedes sumar fechas, por lo que tendrás que pasarlo a segundos y sumar la diferencia, para eso tienes la sentencia `DATEDIFF` y `SUM`

por lo tanto quedaría algo así:

```
SET @Segundos = SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, [START_TIME], [END_TIME]))
```

para sumar la diferencia en segundos

y para convertirlo a un tipo datetime deberias aplicar la siguiente:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(second, @Segundos, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar tu `insert` es:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Horarios
values(@fecha,@fecha,@fechafin)
```

No es bueno no indicar los nombres de las columnas en un `insert`, así como está ahora, imagino que la tabla `Horarios` tiene únicamente 3 columnas, sino este `insert` no funcionaría y ahí el principal problema de no indicar las columnas, si agregamos campos, los `insert` escritos así, dejan de funcionar. La sintaxis óptima sería:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Horarios (fecha1, fecha2, fecha3)
values(@fecha,@fecha,@fechafin)
```

Los nombres son ficticios por que no sé realmente como se llaman en  la tabla.

El otro tema es, es la forma de calcular una nueva fecha en función de una fecha de inicio y una duración. No has aclarado en que unidad se mide la `Duracion` de la cita, pero imaginemos lo más probable que es, que sea en minutos. Si este fuera el caso no necesitas declarar variables para hacer los cálculos y además puede que tampoco sea recomendable. Podríamos hacer directamente el `insert` de la tabla `inserted` que tiene la fila o filas justamente que se han insertado. Algo así

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_horarios] ON [dbo].[Citas] AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Horarios
        SELECT fecha,
               fecha,
               DATEADD(minute, duracion, fecha)
               FROM inserted

END
```

Por último, tienes que tener claro, que a diferencia de otros motores de base de datos, en SQL Server el trigger se ejecuta por sentencia, es decir si insertas un registro o 1.000.000 no importa, el trigger se ejecutará una sola vez. Lo que intentaste hacer usando variables podría eventualmente funcionar cuando insertas una sola fila, pero no funcionaría igual si insertaras mal. La forma que te indique, la de insertar directamente los resultados de `inserted` es consistente con el funcionamiento de los triggers.